# How to compare hash values by key

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash

I have some input data in the following format (tab delineated):

(gene  condition  value)

```
wnt condition1  1
wnt condition2  10
wnt condition3  15
wnt condition4  -1
bmp condition1  10
bmp condition2  inf
bmp condition3  12
bmp condition4  -1
frz condition1  -12
frz condition2  -6
frz condition3  -0.3
```

And am building a HoH as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = read_file('stack.txt');

my %hash;
foreach (@data){
    chomp;
    my ($gene, $condition, $value) = (/^(\w+)\t(\w+\d)\t(-?\d+|-?inf)/);
    $hash{$gene}{$condition} = $value;
}
```

I want to loop through the HoH and, for each gene, print out the values provided all values for that gene are either positive (e.g. 10) or negative (-3). In the data above I would only print out:

```
frz condition1  -12
frz condition2  -6
frz condition3  -0.3
```

As both other genes contain conditions with values that are both positive and negative:

```
wnt condition1  1
wnt condition2  10
wnt condition3  15
wnt condition4  -1 # discrepancy

bmp condition1  10
bmp condition2  inf
bmp condition3  12
bmp condition4  -1 # discrepancy
```

I can loop through as follows, but am not sure how to make comparisons between one HoH value and the 'next' value for that gene condition key combo:

```
for my $gene (sort keys %hash) { 
     for my $condition (sort keys %{$hash{$gene}}) {
        my $value = $hash{$gene}{$condition};
        print "$gene\t$condition\t$value\n" if $value  =~ m/-/;  # This obviously will only print out negative values. I want to compare all values here, and if they are all positive, or all negative, print them.        
    }
}
```

Let me know If I can clarify this further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves the problem by checking all the values in the hash for each gene and incrementing `$neg` if the value contains a minus sign, otherwise `$pos`. If either the positive count or the negative count is zero then all values are of the same sign and the data for that gene is sorted and displayed.

*Note* that this counts `inf` and `0` as positive, which may or may not be what is wanted.

Note that using `read_file` is wasteful as it pulls the entire file into memory at once. Instead of looping over an array you may as well use a `while` loop and read from the file line by line. With `use autodie` there is no need to check the success of the file `open` call.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'stack.txt';

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($gene, $condition, $value) = split /\t/;
  $data{$gene}{$condition} = $value;
}

while (my ($gene, $values) = each %data) {

  my ($pos, $neg) = (0, 0);

  ++(/-/ ? $neg : $pos) for values %$values;

  unless ($neg and $pos) {
    for my $condition (sort keys %$values) {
      printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $gene, $condition, $values->{$condition};
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
frz condition1  -12
frz condition2  -6
frz condition3  -0.3
```

Comment: How would I go about extending the while loop to a HoHoA?

Comment: @FlyingFrog: It depends what you want to do. You should ask another question. I take it you have multiple values for the same gene/condition?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing one value with its neighbor in isolation, you can iterate over the entire list of values for a given gene and increment separate counters for positive and negative values, and then compare the counts to see whether a discrepancy exists.

Assuming your data matches the following scheme:

```
'bmp' => HASH(0x7324710)
   'condition1' => 10
   'condition2' => 'inf'
   'condition3' => 12
   'condition4' => '-1'
'frz' => HASH(0x7323c78)
   'condition1' => '-12'
   'condition2' => '-6'
   'condition3' => '-0.3'
'wnt' => HASH(0x72a5c30)
   'condition1' => 1
   'condition2' => 10
   'condition3' => 15
   'condition4' => '-1'
```

This replacement, for the last code block in your question, will give you the result you need:

```
for my $gene (sort keys %hash) {
    # These variables will contain:
    # - Counts of positive and negative values
    my ($pos_vals, $neg_vals) = (0, 0);
    # - A true/false value indicating whether discrepancy exists
    my $discrepant = undef;
    # - A list of the values of all conditions for a given gene
    my @values = ();

    # Collect condition values for this gene into @values
    my @values = values %{ $hash{$gene} };

    # For each such value, test for a leading - and increment
    # the positive or negative value count accordingly
    for @values { $_ =~ m/^-/ ? $neg_vals++ : $pos_vals++ };

    # If neither counter is zero (i.e. both evaluate true), then
    # a discrepancy exists; otherwise, one doesn't -- either way,
    # we put the test result in $discrepant so as to produce a
    # cleaner test in the following if statement
    $discrepant = (($pos_vals > 0) and ($neg_vals > 0));

    # In the absence of a discrepancy...
    if (not $discrepant) {
        # iterate over the conditions for this gene and print the gene
        # name, the condition name, and the value
        # NB: this is somewhat idiomatic Perl, but you'll tend to see
        # it from time to time and it's thus worth knowing about
        print "$gene\t$_\t$hash{$gene}->{$_}\n"
          foreach sort keys %{ $hash{$gene} };
    };
}
```

**NB**: This will handle both positive and negative infinity correctly, but will treat zero as positive, which may not be correct for your case. Do zero values occur in your data? If so, should they be treated as positive, negative, or neither?

Comment: @FlyingFrog Glad to be of help!

Comment: This is a misuse of `map`, as `for @values { $_ =~ m/^-/ ? $neg_vals++ : $pos_vals++ }` will do just fine. Also, many, including me, would consider it a misuse of the conditional expression, as it is not good practice to use it to modify its own parameters.

Comment: @Borodin Good point re: `map`; I'll edit the answer. With regard to the conditional expression, while I'll grant it's cheating by dint of only being used for side effects, I don't see how it is modifying its parameter; `$_` isn't being changed, and the result of `map` is thrown away.

Comment: @AaronMiller: The "trinary" conditional expression has three parameters and is intended to *return* either the second or the third parameter according to the value of the first. Here you are using it to *modify* the second or third parameters, and discarding the result of the operator. It is frowned upon for the same reason as discarding the list that `map` generates is disliked.

Comment: @FlyingFrog: Please remember to accept an answer once you are satisfied that you have chosen the best one for your needs.

Comment: @Borodin Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, I'm cheating by using the ternary operator as a more concise `if`, and if I were writing Lisp here instead of Perl, I'd feel bad about doing something like that.

Comment: @AaronMiller: See my answer for a legitimate and neater way. It uses the fact that the conditional operator can be used to return an L-value.

Answer (score -1):

```
my @data = <$your_file_handle>;

my %hash;
foreach (@data){
    chomp;
    my ($gene, $condition, $value) = split; #Sorry, your regex didn't work for me, 
                                            #hence the change.
    $hash{$gene}{$condition} = $value;
}

for my $gene (sort keys %hash){
    my $values = join '', values $hash{$gene};
    my $num = %{$hash{$gene}}/1;  #Number of conditions

    #when no '-' is detected or number of '-' matches the one of conditions, print.
    say $gene if ($values !~ /-/ or $values =~ tr/-/-/ == $num); 
}
```

Comment: You can't use just `split` as you don't know for sure that the data doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Also the *complete data* is required as output, not just the gene names, and the number of elements in a hash is generally determined using `my $num = keys %{$hash{$gene}}`.

Comment: 1. You may check how to use `split` and see which use of ours is more robust. 2. If he knows how to 'perl', he should be able to find out how to generate output. That's why I only focus on the 'Real problem' 3. Your vote? huh...

Comment: And 'generally' determined.. Remember TMTOWTDI?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean: I know how to use `split`. Without any parameters it will split on spaces as well as tabs, which may or may not be wrong so it's best to be explicit. And TMTOWTDI isn't a licence to write any old rubbish. You're dividing a string like `'4/8'` by the number 1, and it's far from clear what effect that has. With warnings enabled your code will throw a `Argument "4/8" isn't numeric in division` warning.

Comment: Genes don't have spaces. And the possibility of having space in the `condition` strings or the `values` isn't more likely than having tabs. For the 4/8.. It won't collapse until they change how %hash returns in scalar context.

Comment: You clearly have no interest in improving your programming skills, so that is all the explanation I am going to offer.